# Function to Calculate Sample Size Across a Range

Tags: r, function, sampling

I'm trying to work with the power.prop.test built in function in R to take a data set like the following:

```
Test  P1  P2       Population
1     0.1   0.11   1000
2     0.1   0.12   1500
```

and use the power.prop.test function co calculate the n for each Test scenario. I thin want to divide the population by the n to get rounded down whole number max test scenarios like this:

```
Test  P1  P2       Population    n     Max Tests
1     0.1   0.11   1000          450   2
2     0.1   0.12   1500          335   4
```

I think I need to iterate over the power.prop.test function and extract the n from each iteration and append it to a table, but I'm not sure how to proceed. Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What power value are you using? It would help to see all the parameters used for `power.prop.test`. It's hard to see how your `P1`, `P2` gives rise to your example values of `n`.

Answer (score 0):

First add the appropriate columns to the data frame. Then, loop through each row to do what you want.

```
df$MaxTests <- df$n <- 0
power.val = .85
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    df$n[i] <- floor(power.prop.test(p1=df$P1[i],p2=df$P2[i],power=power.val,sig.level=0.05)$n)
    df$MaxTests[i] <- floor(df$Population[i]/df$n[i])
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This was exactly what i was looking for and a great start for me to expand to other solutions. Your assistance is truly appreciated!